# Re point app tier to new database on new hardware

Tags: tfs

I used "Remove Feature" of TFS admin console which has a URL "test-test-app1\tfs" and i pointed it to new datatier which is already connected to a app tier say "oldtest-oldtest-app1:8080\tfs". Now when i use the ChangeUrl in the new app tier "test-test-app1:8080\tfs" it changes the URL of the existing app tier 'oldtest-oldtest-app1:8080\tfs to "test-test-app1:8080\tfs" and vice versa. So  how can i make each app tier has its own URL

I have tried the below thing: 
I uninstalled the app tier and reinstalled it and configured it to the new data tier even then same error poped up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing the location of the database tier you need to follow the documented approach to move your TFS instance to new hardware:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(v=vs.120).aspx